# Take the first value in a variable as a variable name in R

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, character, rename

In R, I'm trying to take the first value of a character variable and use it to rename the same variable or even to assign a name to another new variable, but I haven't figured out how to do this.

Example:

```
PR <- data.frame("Variable1" = c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"), 
"Variable2" = seq(1:4))

PR
      Variable1 Variable2
1       Red         1
2      Blue         2
3     Green         3
4    Yellow         4
```

I know one could just use "PR %>% rename(Red = Variable1)", but I want R to take this name from the variable directly. The outcome should be:

```
       Red      Variable2
1       Red         1
2      Blue         2
3     Green         3
4    Yellow         4
```

I've trayed to use "rename()" function from dplyr to make it but it didn't work:

```
 PR <- PR %>% rename(as.name(Variable1)[1] = Variable1)
Error: unexpected '=' in "PR <- PR %>% rename(as.name(Variable1)[1] ="
```

How could I do this using dplyr, or even in the context of creating a new variable with the "mutate()" command (for example if I want to create a new variable which name is the first value of "Variable1")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> PR
  Variable1 Variable2
1       Red         1
2      Blue         2
3     Green         3
4    Yellow         4
> name <- PR$Variable1[1]
> PR %>% rename(!!sym(name) := Variable1)
     Red Variable2
1    Red         1
2   Blue         2
3  Green         3
4 Yellow         4
>
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked perfectly! I just have a final question: what does the parts "!!" and ":=" mean?

Comment: So dplyr used something called non-standard evaluation, which is we can directly use column names as if they were object names for ex: df %>% select(variable1), here variable1 is a column name. But in our example, it's looking for first value of Variable1, that is Red, which rename can't find, therefore we need to convert it into symbol. Just look up Non Standard Evaluation, you'd get better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a special substitute.

```
library(tidyverse)

PR <- data.frame("Variable1" = c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"), 
                 "Variable2" = seq(1:4))

#Note the sequence of commands
PR %>%
  mutate(Variable3 = PR$Variable1[1]) %>%
  rename(!!PR$Variable1[1] := Variable1)

#      Red Variable2 Variable3
# 1    Red         1       Red
# 2   Blue         2       Red
# 3  Green         3       Red
# 4 Yellow         4       Red
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
PR %>% 
    rename_at(vars(Variable1), ~ PR$Variable1[1])
#.     Red Variable2
#1    Red         1
#2   Blue         2
#3  Green         3
#4 Yellow         4
```